# Every nth item from array starting from somewhere in array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to get every nth element of a dynamic array, starting from a value somewhere in the array. I need to pick out certain values from one array, and Im going to append them to another.

Basically this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{

    if (i % 5 == 0) // but starting at value 200 and every 5th from here
    {
        // get value
    }
    if (i % 50 == 0) // but starting from value 350 and every 50th value from here
    {
        // get value
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `(array.Length / 2) + i % 5 == 0`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs. Be sure to include inputs with an even number of entries, and inputs with an odd number of entries.

Comment: Why dont you put a helper value into the for loop, its value is 5 basicly and if you reach the starting value, you reach this helper value and starting value.

Comment: @ Jordy van Eijk, sorry my questioning is confusion, didn't mean literally right in the middle of the array, but at a location in the array which is not in the beginning.

Comment: What is the significance of `200` and `350`?

Comment: `const int firstThreshold = 200; const int secondThreshold = 350; for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { if (i >= firstThreshold && (i - firstThreshold) % 5 == 0) { ... } if (i >= secondThreshold && (i - secondThreshold) % 50 == 0) { ... } }` maybe?

Comment: @ Corak and  DiabloSteve, thanks for the tip on the value helper, thats what I need :)

Comment: @agrom - Then please change the question title to reflect that you don't actually mean the exact middle of an array.

Comment: @Corak, Will do!

Comment: //x is starting point >0 and < array.Length
    int y= 1; //first we start with every value
    for (int i = x; i < array.Length; i+=y)
    {
      //get value
      if (i % 5 == 0) // but starting at value 200 and every 5th from here
      {
        //get value
        x = 200; //back or forth to 200th element
        y = 5;   //steps are now 5 wide
      }
      if (i % 50 == 0) // but starting from value 350 and every 50th value from here
      {
        // get value
        x = 350; //back or forth to 350th element
        y = 50; //steps are now 50 wide
      }
    }

Answer (score 1):

This will get you every 5th element after the halfway point:

```
int[] subarr = array.Where((i, val) => (i >= array.Length / 2 && i % 5 == 0)).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will still execute the `i >=` conditional expression for _every element_ in the array. Maybe lead with `.Skip()` to avoid that, but in this case an old-school `for` loop might just be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = (int)(array.Length / 2); i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0) // but starting at value 200 and every 5th from here
    {
        // get value
    }
    if (i % 50 == 0) // but starting from value 350 and every 50th value from here
    {
        // get value
    }
}
```

Isn't this what you want?